# Seemingly unsupported unicode character in UILabel

Tags: ios, unicode, nsstring, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` that displays a string coming in from a web service. It seems to be properly displaying some unicode characters, but not all. The string comes from the web service in a JSON object as follows:

`"\u2b51 \u2605 Special Chars"`

This is displayed in the `UILabel` like so:

[image: UILabel inconsistent unicode support]

Clearly, it's displaying the `\u2605` character just fine but not the `\u2b51` character. The font is `Helvetica Neue`--the system font.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in iOS and/or the font?

Comment: How are u creating your string you get from the json object. Did you make sure you are using the utf8 encoding?

Comment: It can't be the encoding because other unicode characters are working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be purely a font issue. The character U+2605 BLACK STAR “★” is relatively common in fonts, so it is probably taken from a system font or a fallback font. The character U+2B51 BLACK SMALL STAR “⭑” is relatively rare; it was added in Unicode 5.1, i.e. rather recently (in the character code world, that is). According to [Fileformat.info data](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2B51/fontsupport.htm), it appears in Code2000, FreeSerif, GNU Unifont, Quivira, STIX, STIXMath, and Symbola. Not much; most computers have none of them (though many Linux systems probably have FreeSerif). Well, it seems that you can add Asana Math and Universalia to the list; still rather limited.